# Properties of Stochastic Interval

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

I'm reading "Limit Thoerem for Stochastic Processes" and finding it hard to calculate the Stochastic interval.For example :

In proposition 2.10,$T$ is a stopping time:

If $A\in\mathcal F_0$,I need to prove that $[0,T_A[=[0,T[\cup(A^c\times\mathbb R)$

If $A=B\cap\{t<T\},B\in\mathcal F_t$,I need to prove that $[0,T_{A^c}[=[0,T[\cup(A\times(t,\infty))$

Remark:$T_A=T1_{\omega\in A}+\infty 1_{\omega\notin A}$

---

For the 1st one:If $\omega\in A^c$,all $t$ satisfy the condition, so $(A^c\times \mathbb R)$,but when $\omega\notin A$,then $t<T$,I think it is not $[0,T[$,It should have some restrictions on $A$.

Same questions for the 2rd one.I think both the 2 parts in $\cup$ is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the proof in the book is correct.

By definition,

$$[0,T_A[ = \{(\omega,t); 0 \leq t < T_A(\omega)\}.$$

Since $T_A(\omega) = \infty$ for $\omega \notin A$ and $T_A(\omega)=T(\omega)$ for $\omega \in A$, we get

$$[0,T_A[ = \{(\omega,t); \omega \in A, 0 \leq t< T(\omega)\} \cup \{(\omega,t); \omega \notin A, t \geq 0\}.$$

Since

$$\{(\omega,t); \omega \notin A, t \geq 0\} \supseteq \{(\omega,t); \omega \notin A, 0 \leq t < T(\omega)\}$$

this implies

$$[0,T_A[ = \{(\omega,t); \omega \in \Omega, 0 \leq t< T(\omega)\} \cup \{(\omega,t); \omega \notin A, t \geq 0\}$$

This proves $$[0,T_A[ = [0,T[ \cup (A^c \times [0,\infty)).$$ The proof of the second one is very similar, I leave it to you.

Comment: @user166445 You are welcome. If the answer satisfies you, you can accept it by clicking on the tick next to it.